# NET8 Blazor how to create the js.map files?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, asp.net-core, blazor, .net-8.0

In my project `NET8` `Blazor` project, I added some JavaScript to use. When I deploy the website to the server, I noticed that some `js.map` are not present, a few of them related to Blazor itself.

[image]

I tried in `Visual Studio` to find a way to generate them but I can't find any.

Is there a way to generate those files?

Comment: are you running into this issue with local development? are you intending to support debug/development features in this environment/website you've deployed to?

Comment: No, those errors are in the production environment. I don't want to support debugging in the production.

Comment: You mean these files are not in the production directory?

Comment: yes, those `js.map` are not in the production directory

Comment: Does "_framework" folder exist? It should generate when publish. Do you upgrade vs to latest?

Comment: The `_framework` folder exists but there is no trace of those files. I use the `NET8`.